# Login, get info of a table, click buttons, etc in a web page from c# app (GET - POST HTTP)

Tags: c#, post, get

I want to get some information of a web page (Where I have customers, current balance, etc) in my C# application. I thought in use POST - GET methods, but I don't know how to use them. The first problem, I have to login in the page:
[Login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvj5X.png)
I guess I have to get boxes id, and button id, then, complete them in the C# app. Next I want to get table contents. The table is like this: [Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWXeH.png)
How I can get customer id, customer name, and customer balance? And if the customer balance is updated, check it on the app? I think with this is to be able to do the rest on my own.

Answer (score 0):

This could be very difficult depending on exactly how the site is architected.  Does the site have an API you might be able to use instead of trying to go through the UI?

If you have no choice, I would consider using something like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) which is basically a scriptable headless browser.  To make it a little easier to use with C#, you might also consider [Selenium WebDriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/) and their [PhantomJSDriver](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/blob/master/binding/java/src/main/java/org/openqa/selenium/phantomjs/PhantomJSDriver.java).

Selenium is used for automated testing of websites, but you can just as easily use it to automate repetitive UI interaction in websites.  The biggest issue you generally face is keeping your scripting from being so brittle that anytime a change is made to the site, it breaks your automation.  You might want to read up on the [Page Object Pattern](https://automatetheplanet.com/page-object-pattern/) as it can help you minimize redundancy and keep your code maintainable.

Also, it was recently announced that [Chrome v59 will be able to be ran headless](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome), so that might ultimately be an alternative to PhantomJS.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. ANd not, the site does not have an API. The site is very, very simple. And, I will read about PhantomJS